# record of one index page is not shown in another index page, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display record(title) from one index page to another, for this I do

In index.haml:-

```
-if @individual.important_event.present?
  -@individual.important_event.each do |event|
    %p
     = link_to event.title, important_events_path
```

In individual.rb:-

```
has_many :important_event
```

In important_event.rb:-

```
belongs_to :individual
```

But it do not work. It gives error "undefined method `each' for #< ImportantEvent:0xbb729c8>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `individual.rb` model, you need to use the plural in your `has_many` statement, like this:

```
has_many :important_events
```

Then you can use: `-@individual.important_events.each` in your view.

Figuring out when you should or shouldn't use plurals in Rails is a pain even if English is your first language.

Comment: +1 although I don't agree that it's a pain to know when to use the plural or the singular.

Comment: Thank you dpassage for your's kind help